# Spring Boot quickstart does not exist in maven repository?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Looking at Spring Boot here:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start

It appears the "Quick Start" says to include:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The following are my current repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I get a connection timed out exception and when I actually look at the repository...

```
http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/
```

There is no 1.0.1! Is there some other repository that the pom.xml should contain?

Error:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.0.0.RC5 from http://repo.spring.io/
 milestone was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-milestones has elapsed or updates are forced. 
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.0.0.RC5 from/to spring-milestones (http://repo.spring.io/
 milestone): connection timed out to http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.0.0.RC5/spring-boot-starter-
 parent-1.0.0.RC5.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It [**exists**](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-parent/) in central repository add following to your pom.xml

```
<project ...>
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: This really isn't necessary for most people (Central is always on your repository path unless someone knobbled your Maven installation).

Comment: @Dave yes it is not required by default unless you have some thing customized in your `settings.xml`